# Using Sqlite MAX - how to return latest in case of few equal max values

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a sqlite table in which I want to select the row with maximum value in a val1 column.

```
id  val1    val2     date

1   28800   39600   2016-09-23T04:23:26Z

2   28800   28800   2016-09-23T07:27:22Z
```

Using CursorLoader the solution I came to is such:

```
 String[] projection = new String[]{DB.COL_ID,
                "MAX(" + DB.COL_VAR1 + ")" + "AS " + DB.COL_VAR1,
                "date(" + DB.COL_TIME + ") AS " + DATE_TIME};

 String selection = "((" +
                DATE_TIME + " >= date('" + from + "')) AND (" + DATE_TIME + " <= date('" + to + "'))" +
                "GROUP BY " + DATE_TIME;

 return new CursorLoader(context, ContentProvider.createUri(DBSleep.class, null), projection, selection, null, sortOrder);
```

This works fine, except in cases like above, when I have a few rows with same maximum value. Sqlite MAX() would select one of them arbitrarily, while I want to select the one with the latest date. (So in the above case the result should be row 2 and not row 1, while Sqlite returns row1).

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Use ORDER BY with LIMIT 1.

Comment: The problem is I need to have GROUP BY in place, as I want to have one value per each day that exists in table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of computing the maximum over the single column, you have to compute the maximum over the combination of both columns. Just append their values, and use [printf()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#printf) to ensure that the number always has a fixed length so that string comparisons on it work:

```
... MAX(printf('%10d', val1) || date) ...
```

Comment: This is a brilliant solution and it worked for me. 
I guess the only other option would be to use MAX on these 2 columns separately and using INNER JOINS. But this would require raw query.